# Little vim regex

Tags: regex, vim

I have a bunch of strings that look like this: `'../DisplayPhotod6f6.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=130'`, and I'd like to take out everything after the question mark, to look like `'../DisplayPhotod6f6.jpg'`.

```
s/\(.\.\.\/DisplayPhoto.\{4,}\.jpg\)*'/\1'/g
```

This regex is capturing some but not all occurences, can you see why?

Comment: Can you give an example of an occurrence that is missed?

Comment: Amardeep, it missed `'../DisplayPhotocef3.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=54'`, `'../DisplayPhotod6f6.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=130'`, many more.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first "." at the beginning of the group ? Could it be replaced by a "'" (single quote) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use macros, sometime simpler than regexp (and interactive) :

```
qa
/DisplayPhoto<Enter>
f?dt'
n
q
```

And then some `@a`, or `20000@a` to go though all lines.

Answer (score 4):

`\.\{4,}` is trying to match 4 or more `.` characters.  What it looks like you wanted is "match 4 or more of any character" (`.\{4,}`) but "match 4 or more non-`.` characters" (`[^.]\{4,}`) might be more accurate.  You'll also need to change the lone `*` at the end of the pattern to `.*` since the `*` is currently applying to the entire `\(\)` group.

Comment: weird it's still not working for `'../DisplayPhotocef3.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=54'`

Answer (score 3):

I think the easyest way to go for this is:

```
s/?.*$/'/g
```

This says: delete everything after the question mark and replace it with a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp: `/(\.\./DisplayPhoto.*\.jpg)/gi`

tested against following examples:

```
../DisplayPhotocef3.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=54
../DisplayPhotod6f6.jpg?t=before&amp;tn=1&amp;id=130
```

will result:

```
../DisplayPhotocef3.jpg
../DisplayPhotod6f6.jpg
```

Comment: That's PCRE, which is different from Vim's regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
%s/\('\.\.\/DisplayPhoto\w\{4,}\.jpg\).*'/\1'/g
```

Some notes:

- % will cause the swap to work on all lines.
- \w instead of '.', in case there are some malformed file names.
- Replace '.' at the start of your matching regex with ' which is exactly what it should be matching.